# Why is my table of contents not appearing with recursive content in ConTeXt?

Tags: table-of-contents, context, recursion

I am working on a textbook that has a repeated structure for 40 chapters. I set up the TeX file to use `\dorecurse` to provide that structure, then it uses `\input` to enter in the data into each section and subsection. Here is a simplified example:

```
\starttext
    \dorecurse{40}{%
        \input chapter\recurselevel_metadata
        \chapter{Title}
            \section{Introduction}
                 \input chapter\recurselevel_introduction
            \section{Reading}
                 \input chapter\recurselevel_reading
            \section{Exercises}
                 \input chapter\recurselevel_exercises
    }
\stoptext
```

The file "chapter1_introduction.tex", for example, contains the introduction text for chapter 1.

The problem I'm having is, though some data is stored in a metadata file, and it displays correctly in the chapter, it does not appear correctly in the table of contents.

I've created a minimal working example, no longer relying on input files, which showcases this error:

```
\setvalue{title1}{Animals}
\setvalue{title2}{Cereals}
\setvalue{title3}{Mountains}

\starttext

    \completecontent

    \dorecurse{3}{%

        \chapter{\getvalue{title\recurselevel}}
            \input knuth
    }

\stoptext
```

When compiled, the chapter titles appear correctly on the pages `\chapter` appears on, however, the `\completecontent` cannot get the values. Note, I also tried simply using `\define` instead of `\getvalue`, but I see the same error.

In my actual case, the `chapter1_metadata` file contains `\define\chaptertitleis{Animals}` and then `\chapter` is defined with `\chapter{\chaptertitleis}`, and `\input chapter\recurselevel_metadata` is called before `\chapter{\chaptertitleis}` is in the `\dorecurse` loop.

Why aren't my table of contents rendering correctly and how can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\recurselevel` is a global counter, so you may have expansion issues. An easy way is using hashes instead:

```
\setvalue{title1}{Animals}
\setvalue{title2}{Cereals}
\setvalue{title3}{Mountains}
\starttext
\completecontent
\dorecurse{3}{\chapter{\getvalue{title#1}}\input{knuth}}
\stoptext
```

but nesting issues will eventually appear. A more robust way implies enabling expansion:

```
\setvalue{title1}{Animals}
\setvalue{title2}{Cereals}
\setvalue{title3}{Mountains}
\setuphead[chapter][expansion=yes]
\starttext
\completecontent
\dorecurse{3}{\chapter{\getvalue{title\recurselevel}}\input{knuth}}
\stoptext
```